# NextJS special characters routes do not work from browser

Tags: next.js

Using NextJS, I am defining some routes in `getStaticPaths` by making an API call:

```js
/**
 * @dev Fetches the article route and exports the title and id to define the available routes
 */
const getAllArticles = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("https://some_api_url");
    const articles = await result.json();

    return articles.results.map((article) => {
        const articleTitle = `${article.title}`;

        return {
            params: {
                title: articleName,
                id: `${article.id}`,
            },
        };
    });
};

/**
 * @dev Defines the paths available to reach directly
 */
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getAllArticles();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
    };
}
```

Everything works most of the time: I can access most of the articles, `Router.push` works with all URLs defined.

However, when the article name includes a **special character** such as `&`, `Router.push` keeps working, but copy/pasting the URL that worked from inside the app to another tab returns a page:

> An unexpected error has occurred.

In the Network tab of the inspector, a `404` get request error (in Network) appears.

The component code is mostly made of API calls such as:

```
await API.put(`/set_article/${article.id}`, { object });
```

With API being defined by axios.

Any idea why it happens and how to make the `getStaticPaths` work with special characters?

Comment: Are you URL-encoding the paths correctly?

Comment: Unrelated, but is there a reason to use `const articleTitle = \`${article.title}\`;` instead of `const articleTitle = article.title;`?

Comment: @Tomalak I don't actually use `const articleTitle = \`${article.title}\`;`, it came with the simplification of the code for StackOverflow ^^
How can I check the URL-encoding? I don't even know what you are talking about, so this may be it...

Comment: Since you're not showing the code that *uses* the paths I can't tell you what you need to change.

Comment: It's mostly API calls such as `await API.put(\`/set_article/${article.id}\`, { object });` with API being defined by axios: `const API = axios.create({ baseURL: someBaseUrl, responseType: "json", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } } );`

Comment: You need to add these things to the question. It does not make a lot of sense to write code into the comments (you should know by now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you transport values in URLs, they *need* to be URL-encoded. (When you transport values in HTML, they need to be HTML encoded. In JSON, they need to be JSON-encoded. And so on. Any text-based system that can transport structured data has an encoding scheme that you need to apply to data. URLs are not an exception.)

Turn your raw values in your client code

```
await API.put(`/set_article/${article.id}`)
```

into encoded ones

```
await API.put(`/set_article/${encodeURIComponent(article.id)}`)
```

It might be tempting, but don't pre-encode the values on the server-side. Do this on the client end, at the time you actually use them in a URL.